# Custome Linux VM Extension on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell

Ttrying to run .sh script via custome script extension via set-azvmextension but nither its througing an error nor output gettting generated on linux vm.

```
  $resourceGroupName = "abc-RG"
  $storageAccountName = "abcdiag"
  $containerName = "public"
  $location = "Central India"
  $vmName = "abclinux2"
  $extensionName = "vm_rwq"
  $deploymentScript = "dd.sh"
  $destintionPath = "/tmp/"
  $storageAccountKeys = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Value
  $storageAccountKey = $storageAccountKeys[0]
  $Settings = @{"fileUris" = "[https://abcdiag.blob.core.windows.net/public/dd.sh]"; "commandToExecute" = "sh dd.sh"};
  $ProtectedSettings = @{"storageAccountName" = $storageAccountName; "storageAccountKey" = $storageAccountKey};
  Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VMName $vmName >>
```

Comment: =========dd.sh script ========

#!/bin/bash
ls -al > /tmp/csc.txt

Comment: Here is the actual command , Above some words are missing
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VMName $vmName -Name "ContosoTest" -Publisher Microsoft.compute -Type "CustomScriptExtension" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.5" -Settings $Settings -ProtectedSettings $ProtectedSettings

Comment: Please update your question directly - don't add information in comments.

Comment: Could you please check the status of the extension via Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use  Azure Custom Script Extension Version 1 with Linux virtual machines, the `publisher` should be `Microsoft.OSTCExtensions` and the `type` should be `CustomScriptForLinux`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript#22-using-azure-powershell)

For example

```
$resourceGroupName = ""
  $storageAccountName = ""
  $location = ""
  $vmName = ""
  $extensionName = "vm_rwq"
  $fileUri = @("https://jimtestperfdiag516.blob.core.windows.net/test/config-music.sh")
  $storageAccountKeys = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name $storageAccountName).Value
  $storageAccountKey = $storageAccountKeys[0]
  $Settings = @{'fileUris' =$fileUri; "commandToExecute" = "./config-music.sh"};
  $ProtectedSettings = @{"storageAccountName" = $storageAccountName; "storageAccountKey" = $storageAccountKey};
  Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VMName $vmName -Name $extensionName -Publisher "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" -Type "CustomScriptForLinux" -TypeHandlerVersion "1.5" -Settings $Settings -ProtectedSettings $ProtectedSettings
```

[image]

---

## Update

According to my research, Azure Custom Script Extension Version 1 does not support Red Hat operating System VM. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linuxostc#operating-system)
[image]

So if you want to install Custom Script Extension on Red Hat VM, we should use the new version: version 2. For further information, please refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux). Besides, if you want to use script to install the extension on Azure Linux VM, [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-extension-set) is a better way.

```
az vm extension set \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --vm-name myVM \ 
  --name customScript \
  --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions \
  --settings ./script-config.json \
  --protected-settings ./protected-config.json
```

But, if you still want to use PowerShell, please refer to the following script

```
$resourceGroupName = ""
  $storageAccountName = ""
  $location = ""
  $vmName = ""
  $extensionName = "vm_rwq"
  $fileUri = @("https://jimtestperfdiag516.blob.core.windows.net/test/config-music.sh")
  $storageAccountKeys = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name $storageAccountName).Value
  $storageAccountKey = $storageAccountKeys[0]
  $Settings = @{'fileUris' =$fileUri; "commandToExecute" = "./config-music.sh"};
  $ProtectedSettings = @{"storageAccountName" = $storageAccountName; "storageAccountKey" = $storageAccountKey};
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VMName $vmName -Name $extensionName `
          -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions" -Type "CustomScript" `
          -TypeHandlerVersion "2.1" -Settings $Settings -ProtectedSettings $ProtectedSettings
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , For your response , Will try and let you know

Comment: Hello There ,
   Still its failing  , i can see extension is  azure portal but status is Unavailable

Comment: @VijayGuptav Could you please try to uninstall the extension and install the extension via Azure Portal?

Comment: @VijayGupta Could you please tell me the version of your Linux VM?

Comment: Hi  , i had uninstalled and ran script but result was same . i am using RHEL 7.4 Linux

Comment: I tested that solution, because I need something similar. I tested on Ubuntu VM, and it worked. My quesrion is if there are some requirements reg. storage account where we store out script file? When I want to add Custom Script Extension via portal, in the wizard I dont see all my storage account. I see only boot diagnostics storage accounts.